# catalyst authentication query is on Password

Tags: authentication, catalyst

I am trying to setup Catalyst for the first time. After debugging for quite sometime to figure out why authentication won't work, realized that the sql query looks like

SELECT me.user_id, me.password, me.role FROM users me WHERE ( **password** = ? ): 'abcd'

the users table ( for the testing pwd is clear text )

user_id PRI
password 
role

Users.pm has 
**PACKAGE**->set_primary_key("user_id");

What could be wrong that the query is on password and not on the user_id ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the configuration hash is not constructed correctly.

I would suggest the `id_field` is pointing to `password` instead of `user_id`. Here's the config from my app (I use Class:DBI, not DBIx::Class which you probably are, but that's not significant). `login_name` is my equivalent of your `user_id`, i.e. the field that the user-id is stored in:

```
my $authenticationconfig = {
    default_realm => 'login_name',

    login_name => {
        credential => {
            class => 'Password',
            password_field => 'password',
            password_type => 'crypted'
        },
        store => {
            class => 'Class::DBI',
            user_class => '__myapp__::__myusertable__',
            id_field => 'login_name' ## have you got password here?
        }
    },
    ... # other realms
};
```

Comment: you are right RET. myapp.yml looks like 

Plugin::Authentication:
  default_realm: members
  realms:
    members:
      credential:
        class: Password
        password_field: password
        password_type: clear
      store:
        class: DBIx::Class
        user_model: Login::Users

and the call to authenticate

Comment: Glad to be able to help. Please consider upvoting and/or ticking the answer if it solved your problem - that's how SO works.

Comment: `$c->authenticate({user_id_field_name => $username , 
                   password_field_name => $password });`

The field name should match with the table users field name.